# Is there any way to get files Id in OfficeJS

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, office-js, office-addins, microsoft-graph-files

I am using Graph API's recently and there is an API get files content by id. Is there any way to get document id so I can call Graph API and get its content ?

```
Excel.run(function(context) {
    var workbookId = context.workbook.id;
    return context.sync()
        .then(function() {
            console.log("Workbook ID: " + workbookId);
        });
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
});
```

I tried this code but it always says undefined

Answer (score 0):

The [Excel.Workbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.workbook?view=excel-js-preview) class doesn't provide the `Id` property. But you may find the [Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-worksheet-id-member) property for the `Excel.Worksheet` class.

Use the [name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.workbook?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-workbook-name-member) property instead in case of workbooks.